# Laravel 4.2 - Update a pivot by its own id

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having some trouble with my pivot table. I've recognized too late, that it is possible, that some pivot rows doesn't have unique values in my project, means I've to add an auto_increment ID field to my pivot table.

This is my structure:

Order.php

```
public function items()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'orders_items', 'order_id', 'item_id')->withPivot(['single_price', 'hours', 'prov', 'nanny_id', 'vat', 'vat_perc', 'invoice_id','id']);
}
```

orders_items

```
id, order_id, item_id, nanny_id, hours
```

I've conntected Orders and Items through a pivot table ('orders_items)'. It is possible, that one order has 2 or more same items in the pivot table. So I've to add an unique ID to identify and update them.

Now I try to update a pivot row. Problem is, if I have 2 or more items, he updates them all, not only one. This is my update command:

```
    $order = Order::find($orderId);

    $items = $order->items()->whereNull('nanny_id');

    $free_item = $items->first();

    $free_item->pivot->nanny_id = 123;
    $free_item->pivot->save();
```

With this command, he updates all pivot rows from the order. I know the problem: Laravel uses here the wrong identifiers (it uses order_id and item_id as defined in my belongsToMany relationship - and they aren't unique). For example, Laravel tries to execute this code on save():

```
UPDATE orders_items SET [...] WHERE order_id = 123 AND item_id = 2;
```

I want, that Laravel changes the query to this one:

```
UPDATE orders_items SET [...] WHERE order_id = 123 AND item_id = 2 AND id = 45;
```

// Edit

Okay, this solution works:

```
$free_item->pivot->where('id',$free_item->pivot->id)->update('nanny_id',123);
```

But is there an easier way, f.e. adding a custom pivot model that adds the id automatically to save() and update() methods?

Comment: What do you mean by *declare the id as identifier when saving*? ID of the pivot row? How do you know which pivot row to update anyway if there are multiple ones of the same values? Not something you want to hear, but the best idea is to tidy up the table and adjust the code, to continue in a clean way. Otherwise this might haunt you.

Comment: Hey, when I call the save() method, Laravel executes the following query: "UPDATE orders_items SET [...] WHERE order_id = 123 AND item_id = 1;"  - order_id and item_id are not unique in orders_items - so it is possible, that Laravel updates all rows in my pivot table with the same combination. I want to add the ID coloumn to the save() method, because I need this update command: "UPDATE orders_items SET [...] WHERE order_id = 123 AND item_id = 1 AND id = 45;".

Comment: Did you try to switch `pivot` in your calls to `wherePivot('id', 45)`? http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_wherePivot

Comment: @lesssugar - I've found a solution, added it in the edit. Problem is, I don't want to call exactly that specific pivot ID on every call, I want to make it "automatic" on save() and update(). I've just tried to define a custom pivot model, but I don't know, how to add the ID column to its saving() method.

Comment: Of course, the `45` was an example.

Comment: Yeah I know, but isn't it the same solution like in the edit?

Comment: Similar. Your code says: `->pivot->where('id', $free_item->pivot->id)` and I proposed (not tested): `->wherePivot('id', $free_item->pivot->id)`. In the end, same thing I guess.